# Concatenate string with integer (Creat a Loop Inside an Id and Click on each Id)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, web-scraping

Please, Guys, I wanna replace **i** with numbers from 101 to 180 so I will get an **Id** for each **i** and also I wanna click on it.

Exemple without loop (Works well) :
`Gg.FindElementById("ListSocieteControl1_ListSociete1_RptrScCote_ctl01_Label2").Click`

But I want to change that 101 so many times using a loop ( from 101 to 180 ) because I have multiple Ids.

**I have tried those solutions but I got errors for both of them.
Any suggestions or solutions.

Thank you in advance,**

`````
 Gg.FindElementById("ListSocieteControl1_ListSociete1_RptrScCote_ct" & i & "_Label2").ClickGg.FindElementById("ListSocieteControl1_ListSociete1_RptrScCote_ctl01_Label2").Click````
==> I got an "Object doesn't support this property or method"


 ````For i = 101 To 180
    Set Num = ("ListSocieteControl1_ListSociete1_RptrScCote_ct" & i & "_Label2")
    Gg.FindElementById(Num).Click````
==> object required error
`````

Comment: `Num` should be a string so you cannot use `Set` statement. Just assign like this: `Num = "ListSocieteControl1_ListSociete1_RptrScCote_ct" & i & "_Label2"`. And it looks like you did not declare `Num` (or did not declare as `String`, it is good practice to declare ALL your variables, please put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to help you enforce it

Comment: Looks like selenium syntax in which there is no `ClickGg` method. At some point did you accidentally merge lines?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get rid of the Set command for your string called "num". The set command should be used for objects which is why you are getting the object required error. The code below should work fine.

```
For i = 101 To 180
    Num = ("ListSocieteControl1_ListSociete1_RptrScCote_ct" & i & "_Label2")
    Gg.FindElementById(Num).Click
next i
```